# Prove or disprove inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge a^rb^{2-r}+b^rc^{2-r}+c^ra^{2-r}$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers greater than $0$ and $r$ is a real number with $0 \le r \le 2$. Does inequality $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge  a^rb^{2-r}+b^rc^{2-r}+c^ra^{2-r}$$ hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, since $(2,0)$ majorizes $(r, 2-r)$, by Muirhead's inequality, the result is true.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead's_inequality

Comment: I get $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge \frac{a^rb^{2-r}+b^rc^{2-r}+c^ra^{2-r}+a^{2-r}b^r+b^{2-r}c^r+c^{2-r}a^r}{2}$$

Comment: Muirhead is for symmetric polynomial inequalities, the RHS is cyclic, not symmetric :(.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use Rearrangement Inequality, noting $a^r, b^r, c^r$ and $a^{2-r}, b^{2-r}, c^{2-r}$ are similarly ordered.